# How to get input text box the same size as a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

On the website I'm working on I have noticed that the `input` boxes are not the same size as my `p`'s. In FF a `p` has a default size of 20px and a `input` is 17, but if you set both of them to 1em the `p` stays the same, as expected, but the `input` increases to 21. Why does the `input` increase with 1em, by definition it should stay the same? How can I easily get all font's on my page the same size? I have also checked this with IE and I get the same results. Even if I use PX it does the same thing.

```html
<p>p = 20px</p>
<p style="font-size:1em;">p with 1em = 20px</p>

<input type="text" value="input text = 17"><br>

<input type="text" value="input text w/ 1em = 21" style="font-size:1em;"><br>

<input type="text" value="input text w/ 17px = 22" style="font-size:17px;"><br>
```

Comment: The code is working correctly for me. Do you have other CSS that might be overriding your inline style?

Comment: @Joseph Beard what browser are you using?

Comment: BrianC987, I tested it in Chome and Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like the input boxes use a different font family if I add `* {font-family: "Helvetica";}` all the fonts that are set to 1em are the correct size. Still not sure why the unstyled input is not the same size, but setting to 1em sets it to the correct size.

```css
* {font-family: "Helvetica";}
```

```html
<p>p = 20px</p>
<p style="font-size:1em;">p with 1em = 20px</p>

<input type="text" value="input text = 17"><br>

<input type="text" value="input text w/ 1em = 20" style="font-size:1em;"><br>

<input type="text" value="input text w/ 17px = 21" style="font-size:17px;"><br>
```

Comment: The different font families are only because the code snippet is using Stackoverflow's style sheet when running on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

em units for font-size are based off the elements default font-size. 1em on p and and input might be have different results because they start at a different default font-size.

Try just giving them explicit pixel values instead:

**CSS**

```
p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

input {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Or give your site a little reset:

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: If I use px it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely culprits here: font, and box model. Because the `em` unit is based on the size of the font, different font families or sizes in your `p` and `input` will lead to different values of `em`.

Box model defines how the `width` and `height` values are handled: does it measure to the inside of the padding (`content-box`) or the outside of the border (`border-box`). You can set the box model with the `box-model` CSS attribute.

Comment: `box-model` seems to have no effect. This makes sense as I'm only changing the font-size not the padding or margin.

Comment: The input already has border, padding and margin by default, so setting its size will be impacted by box-model unless you've removed those.

Answer (score 0):

So, the second input's text is actually being sized according to the standard p tag font-size. Thus, if the default font-size of the `p` tag is `16px`, `1em` will equal `16px` no matter what element you style. Here's an example showing this:

```js
alert('Font-size of second input: ' + $('.input-2').css('font-size'));
```

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.input-2 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Unstyled p tag</p>
<p>P tag with font-size of 1em</p>

<input type="text" value="Name" />
<input class="input-2" type="text" value="Name" />
```

To fix this issue, I would recommend using `px` units as these are absolute. Here's an article that explains CSS size units: https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

**Edit**

Here's a pen demonstrating how to use pixels instead of `em`s:

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}

p, input {
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<p>Unstyled p tag</p>
<p>P tag with font-size of 1em</p>

<input type="text" value="Name" />
<input class="input-2" type="text" value="Name" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have changed the code to show that px does the same thing.

Comment: What are you setting the value to in px?

Comment: I set it 17px because that is what FF said the computed value was with no styling.

Comment: I added a demonstration of how to use pixels instead of `em`s.

Comment: This did help me, but it's not the difference between px and em. In this example you also added `* {font-family: font}` that was the missing piece. Apparently the input boxes are a different font.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You'll notice that in your question the `p` tags have a serif font, while the `input` tags have a sans-serif font. If this helps, consider marking the answer as correct.